# Lost iPhone pictures after uploaded to iPhoto

Tags: photos.app, photos, iphone, file-transfer, image-capture

My iPhone was running out of space and I noticed I had over 1000 photos. Like usual I upload them to my computer using Image Capture then at the bottom I click "delete pictures after" so they aren't on my phone anymore.

They uploaded perfectly fine to Image Capture, but when I clicked on "transfer to iPhoto" I got a message saying the disk was full and now I can't find the picture files.

Comment: Hmm, never seen anything like that before. Can you go to your user folder and sort by date modified? Might be worth looking in the iPhoto trash as well just in case.

Comment: I looked for by the date modified and there are just picture files and when i clicked on it it opened up to text edit, the file name looks like this "Photo.004440.ipmeta" and nothing is in the iphoto trash :(

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had a look around and this [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2409083?start=0&tstart=0) might help you. Read all the posts for context but the important one is the last post by Old Toad, he is something of an iPhoto expert on the Apple forums. He says this:

> I don't use IC for my imports but have one possible idea: While in the Finder use the Go->Go to Folder menu and enter "/volumes". See if there is anything in that folder other than alias to the various volumes you work with on a regular basis.
>
> If you know the name of any of the files that are missing download and use [Find Any File](http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.html) to search for it. FAF will search areas that Spotlight can't."